# OpenMP parallelization with array elements

Tags: c++, openmp, eigen

I've been playing around with OpenMP, and am trying to see if I can get a speedup in a particular bit of C++ code.

```
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (Index j=alignedSize; j<size; ++j)
    {
      res[j] = cj.pmadd(lhs0(j), pfirst(ptmp0), res[j]);
      res[j] = cj.pmadd(lhs1(j), pfirst(ptmp1), res[j]);
      res[j] = cj.pmadd(lhs2(j), pfirst(ptmp2), res[j]);
      res[j] = cj.pmadd(lhs3(j), pfirst(ptmp3), res[j]);
    }
```

I'm a complete newbie with OpenMP so be gentle with me, but could someone shed some light on why this code ends up doubling the execution time rather than speeding it up?

I'm running with 4 cores, just in case that matters.

Comment: How did you measure time? What are your specific results? Can you provide the code in form of a [mcve]? What is the specific processor model and memory setup of the system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the size of a `res` entry? If its less than the size of a cache line then its likely [false sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing).

Comment: A res entry is 8 bytes long, and so assuming a 64 byte long cache line, it looks like I would want to assign 8 iterations per thread? Something like `#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static,8)` ?

Answer (score 0):

A bare minimum for typical cpu would be chunks of 128 bytes and then you would need unified last level cache.